Querying a BigQuery table clustered by geography does not improve performance when intersecting with geographies from other tables
I have a large (250 Gb) BigQuery table representing a grid of values, with the grid cells stored as polygons. The table is clustered by this geography column. I have a second table with various polygons, and I want to get grid cell values within one of these polygons (For example, query some weather data within the boundaries of a specific country).
When I perform a spatial intersection of the grid table with a single polygon using ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON, I see that the query cost (bytes processed) is low (100 Mb). But when I perform the same query with the polygon as a part of a select statement I see that the table is fully scanned and the cost is high (250 Gb).
This is a reproducible example. When querying the following public dataset using a specific polygon:
SELECT npp FROM `bigquery-public-data.modis_terra_net_primary_production.MODIS_MOD17A3HGF` 
WHERE year=2020
AND ST_INTERSECTS(geography_polygon, ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -101.1, 50 ], [ -101, 50 ], [ -101, 56 ], [ -101.1, 56 ], [ -101.1, 50 ] ] ] }'))

-- Bytes processed
-- 785.45 MB
-- Bytes billed
-- 786 MB
With the same polygon as part of a select statement in a table:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `tmp.polygon`
AS SELECT ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON('{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -101.1, 50 ], [ -101, 50 ], [ -101, 56 ], [ -101.1, 56 ], [ -101.1, 50 ] ] ] }') geog;

SELECT npp FROM `bigquery-public-data.modis_terra_net_primary_production.MODIS_MOD17A3HGF` 
WHERE year=2020
AND ST_INTERSECTS(geography_polygon, (SELECT geog FROM `tmp.polygon`))

-- Bytes processed
-- 522.15 GB
-- Bytes billed
-- 522.15 GB
I got the same results using cross joins or inner joins.
Why doesn't clustering work with the select statements?
Is there a way to decrease the query cost without adding custom clustering / partitioning columns?

This optimization is only implemented by BigQuery for constant geography in the filter.
A work around is to split the query into two parts using BigQuery procedural language (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language).
DECLARE poly GEOGRAPHY;
SET poly = (SELECT geog FROM `tmp.polygon`);

SELECT npp FROM `bigquery-public-data.modis_terra_net_primary_production.MODIS_MOD17A3HGF` 
WHERE year=2020
AND ST_INTERSECTS(geography_polygon, poly);

This bills 786 MB.
Update for the case when the polygon is too complex and causes evaluation limit error: let's store bounding box only, and post-filter using the actual polygon:
DECLARE box STRUCT<minx FLOAT64, miny FLOAT64, maxx FLOAT64,  maxy FLOAT64>;
SET box = (SELECT ST_BoundingBox(geog) FROM `tmp.polygon`);

SELECT npp FROM `bigquery-public-data.modis_terra_net_primary_production.MODIS_MOD17A3HGF` 
WHERE year=2020
AND ST_INTERSECTS(geography_polygon, (SELECT geog FROM `tmp.polygon`))
AND ST_INTERSECTSBOX(geography_polygon, box.minx, box.miny, box.maxx, box.maxy);

This also bills 786 MB, although in rare cases it might bill more due to more lax filter.

Thanks. This indeed works, however it fails for complex polygons with Script expression exceeded evaluation limit of 1048576 bytes at [2:12]. Even after simplifying the polygon significantly.

Maybe compute convex hull of the polygon. This should not change query cost, but should reduce poly size. You can then combine rough filter with context hull and precise filter with polygon from (select ...) query.

If even that fails, maybe switch to ST_BoundingBox and ST_IntersectsBox, plus ST_Intersects with (select ...).
